# Configure Keycloak with server certificate bundle

Tags: https, bundle, keystore, keycloak

I have configured HTTPS on a Keycloak server by placing a certificate `A.crt` in a Java keystore and configuring that keystore in `standalone.xml`. HTTPS access has worked well from a given client so far. The certificate is signed by an intermediate CA `B`, which is signed by a root CA `C`.

I now encounter problems when accessing Keycloak from another client. It says: "unable to get local issuer certificate" or "certificate signed by unknown authority" (depending on the client software). I'm quite sure the root cause is that CA certificate `B.crt` is not known to this client. A strong indication is that I can access Keycloak from that client with `curl --cacert B.crt https://keycloak...`.

Since I cannot predict which clients will have what CA certificates installed I would like to configure a bundle consisting of `A.crt`, `B.crt`, and `C.crt` as root certificate. If this were a server that directly took a PEM certificate I would use the bundle resulting from `cat A.crt B.crt C.crt > bundle.crt`, but because of its use of a Java keystore this is not an option with Keycloak.

So how can I store a server certificate bundle (it that's the right terminology) into a Java keystore so that Keycloak can make use of it in such a way that "all" clients can access the service?

**UPDATE** I've tried adding the intermediate and root certificates `B` and `C` to the keystore already used by Keycloak, but this did not solve the current issue:

```
keytool -import -alias b -file B.crt -keystore $KEYSTORE
keytool -import -alias c -file C.crt -keystore $KEYSTORE
```

Answer (score 0):

You said having a keystore configured in your standalone.xml where A.crt was imported, but do you have a truststore? You could try adding B.crt in your truststore.